# Pyspark flatten rows with multiple values per ID into multiple columns

Tags: pyspark

I am using PySpark to transform join several dataframes, but one of the dataframe columns contains multiple values per ID, resulting in multiple rows for those IDs.  I need to flatten those rows into one one, with a unique column for each value.  My data looks like this:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some text |
| 1 | more text |
| 1 | still more text |
| 2 | some text |
| 2 | still more text |
| 3 | null |

...and the final transformation should look like this:

| ID | Text_1 | Text_2 | Text_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some text | more text | still more text |
| 2 | some text | still more text | null |
| 3 | null | null | null |

How can I do this without using up too much memory?

I was able to group the data by ID to count how many columns it needs to be expanded to, but I'm unsure how to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you started works:

**1. Create the input dataframe:**

```python
spark = ...
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    [1,     'some text'],
    [1,     'more text'],
    [1,     'still more text'],
    [2,     'some text'],
    [2,     'still more text'],
    [3,     None]
], ["ID", "Text"])
```

**2. Group the dataframe by `ID` and count the number of strings for each `ID`:**

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('ID').agg(F.collect_list('Text').alias('Text')) \
    .withColumn('cnt', F.size('Text')).cache()
```

The `cache` is important here as the `df2` dataframe will be used twice.

**3. Get the maximum number of strings for a single `ID`**

```python
max = df2.agg(F.max('cnt')).first()[0]
```

**4. Select the correct element of the collected array for each column**

```python
textcols = [F.col('Text')[i].alias(f'Text_{i+1}') for i in range(0, max)]
df2.select([F.col('ID')] + textcols).orderBy('ID').show()
```

Result:

```
+---+---------+---------------+---------------+
| ID|   Text_1|         Text_2|         Text_3|
+---+---------+---------------+---------------+
|  1|some text|      more text|still more text|
|  2|some text|still more text|           null|
|  3|     null|           null|           null|
+---+---------+---------------+---------------+
```